# Replace a directive by another one without compiling children nodes twice

Tags: angularjs

In a project, I have built a directive *aDir* that is replaced by another one *bDir* using $compile in its post-link function. It creates a "shortcut" for *bDir* which is useful because *bDir* has many arguments and I use it all accross the project.

In my templates:

```
<p>
    <button a-dir></button>
</p>
```

Which is compiled in:

```
<p>
    <button b-dir arg1="" arg2="" ... ></button>
</p>
```

It works great with a code like this:

```
function aDir($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
      iElem.attr('b-dir', '');
      iElem.attr('arg1', '');
      iElem.attr('arg2', '');
      [...]
      iElem.removeAttr('a-dir'); // To avoid infinite loop
      $compile(iElem)(scope);
    }
  }
}
```

Nevertheless, if the element on which *aDir* is apply has children, they will be compiled twice. Once by the `$compile` function initiated by Angular and once by the `$compile` function I call in *aDir* post-link.

Consider [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SXfkVyaQ0JrwEAqI4xov?p=info). This is the HTML:

```
<outer-level>
  <p replace-by-another>
    <inner-level>Hello World!</inner-level>
  </p>
</outer-level>
```

*replaceByAnother* is replaced by the directive called *another*. *outerLevel* and *innerLevel* are directives that does nothing but log in the console when their compile, pre and post link functions are called.

The console logs are:

```
outerLevel: compile
replaceByAnother: compile
innerLevel: compile
outerLevel: pre link
replaceByAnother: pre link
innerLevel: pre link
innerLevel: post link
replaceByAnother: post link
    another: compile
    innerLevel: compile
    another: pre link
    innerLevel: pre link
    innerLevel: post link
    another: post link
outerLevel: post link
```

So we have two calls of compile, pre link and post link functions of *innerLevel*. In my case that's totally ok but I'm interested in understanding entirely what `$compile` does and if such a behavior could be avoided.

I tried a couple of things by defining a compile function in *replaceByAnother* directive but I just manage to change the order of execution and not to compile just once *innerLevel* directive:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZnBRaskb1WPkRZv36giS

```
function replaceByAnother($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function(tElem, tAttrs){
      console.log('replaceByAnother: compile');
      tElem.attr('another', '');
      tElem.removeAttr('replace-by-another');
      var anotherLinkFunc = $compile(tElem);

      return {
        pre: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
          console.log('replaceByAnother: pre link');
        },
        post: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
          console.log('replaceByAnother: post link');
          anotherLinkFunc(scope);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the results:

```
outerLevel: compile
replaceByAnother: compile
  another: compile
  innerLevel: compile
innerLevel: compile
outerLevel: pre link
replaceByAnother: pre link
innerLevel: pre link
innerLevel: post link
replaceByAnother: post link
  another: pre link
  innerLevel: pre link
  innerLevel: post link
  another: post link
outerLevel: post link
```

Do you have any idea?

**SOLUTION**

With the answers of @georgeawg and @AndrésEsguerra, I found a satisfacting solution:

- Use `terminal: true` and a high priority to prevent Angular from compiling twice children nodes.
- Modify the template element in the compile function and call `$compile` on it. Store the output of `$compile`.
- Call this output in the link function to bind the template element to the scope.

---

```
function replaceByAnother($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    terminal: true,
    priority: 100000,
    compile: function(tElem, tAttrs){
      tElem.attr('another', '');
      tElem.removeAttr('replace-by-another');
      var anotherLinkFunc = $compile(tElem);

      return {
        pre: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
          // pre link
        },
        post: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
          anotherLinkFunc(scope, function cloneAttachedFn(clone) {
              iElem.replaceWith(clone);
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the first inner compile by cloning `tElem` and emptying it during the compile phase.

```
//replaceByAnother Directive
function replaceByAnother($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function(tElem, tAttrs){
      console.log('replaceByAnother: compile');
      //clone tElem
      var tClone = tElem.clone();
      //empty tElem
      tElem.empty();
      return {
        pre: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
          //console.log('replaceByAnother: pre link');
        },
        post: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
          //console.log('replaceByAnother: post link');
          //modify and compile cloned elements
          tClone.attr('another', '');
          tClone.removeAttr('replace-by-another');
          var linkFn = $compile(tClone);
          linkFn(scope, function transclude(clone) {
              iElem.append(clone);
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then modify and compile the cloned elements in the postLink phase.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/KUwylA6vz0e20H306wQb?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you @georgeawg, I find your solution quite surprising but it actually works as expected!

Answer (score 4):

Use `terminal: true` and a high priority. AngularJS compiles directives by highest to lowest priority, so any directive with a higher priority will be compile before yours

Docs: [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

```
function replaceByAnother($compile){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    terminal: true,
    priority: 1000000,
    compile: function(tElem, tAttrs){
      console.log('replaceByAnother: compile');
      tElem.attr('another', '');
      tElem.removeAttr('replace-by-another');
      var anotherLinkFunc = $compile(tElem);

      return {
        pre: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
          console.log('replaceByAnother: pre link');
        },
        post: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
          console.log('replaceByAnother: post link');
          anotherLinkFunc(scope);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! Now I better understand when I should use 'terminal' and 'priority'. Now, is there a way to preserve the natural order of execution of pre-link and post-link functions ? Because with your solution, pre-link of 'another' is executed after post-link of 'replaceByAnother', and post-link of innerLevel after post-link of 'replaceByAnother'.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think `pre-link` and `post-link` are not grouped for all directives (like, applying all pre functions and then all post functions) but they are applied together for each directive, and directives are applied according to dom element (outer to inner) and when they're on the same element, priority decides which one is applied first.
Edit: reading the docs, when on the same element, first all pre-link are applied in priority order, then all post-link in reverse order.

Comment: Actually your solution doesn't work in any situation because "the template instance and the link instance may be different objects if the template has been cloned", for instance when you use an `ng-if`. In this case, some issues may arise. See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ITHQcoipzFp29AvME3G6) for an example.